# I am not able to manipulate a Symbol that is nested within another Symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, nested, symbols

I'm a new coder and first time question asker. I'm working on a program that shows a math problem where each digit is represented by a Symbol. In order to make it easier to manipulate the size of the problem I want to make a Symbol "problem" and put the Symbols of "digit" inside it. "problem" is the name of the instance of Symbol "Problem" on the stage. The different digits are instances of the Symbol "Number" and are named like this "digit01, digit02, digit03, digit11..." up to "digit33" I want the program to cycle through all of the digits to make them stop at the first frame.

This is the relevant portion of my code:

```
for (var u: int = 0; u < 4;u++)
{
   for (var v: int = 1; v < 4;v++)
   {
       this["problem.digit" + u + v].gotoAndStop(1);
   }
}
```

When I run this I get Error #1069. "problem.digit01 not found on Main_Math and there is no default value."

Incidentally it works when I write the digits individually like this:

```
problem.digit01.gotoAndStop(1);
problem.digit02.gotoAndStop(2);
```

etc..

I appreciate any guidance you can offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing is not working like that. You cannot address child's children with a single [] operation. Also, it's better to use getChildByName method because dot syntax access works only with publish option "automatically declare stage instances".

```
for (var u: int = 0; u < 4;u++)
{
    for (var v: int = 1; v < 4;v++)
    {
        // Get a reference to a child and typecast it as MovieClip.
        var aDigit:MovieClip = problem.getChildByName("digit" + u + "" + v) as MovieClip;
        aDigit.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Lets have some things explained.

First, MovieClip is a dynamic class which means you can read and write its instance members without actually declaring them (the difference between dot and bracket syntax explained here [Using . or [ ] to access Object properties - what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097664/using-or-to-access-object-properties-whats-the-difference) ):

```
var M:MovieClip = new MovieClip;

trace(M['a']); // undefined, no error raised
M['a'] = 1;
trace(M['a']); // 1
trace(M.a]);   // 1
```

Second, MovieClip is a DisplayObjectContainer thus it can contain children. These children has names and you can reference them by calling the getChildByName("child name goes here") method, and don't forget to typecast the result because there are all sorts of children so they are typed by their base DisplayObject class by default. The child name is **not** the same thing as object member name (althougt, as I mentioned earlier, "automatically declare stage instances" assigns child references to the variables with the same names behind the scenes):

```
// We proceed working with M from above.

// Lets create a child for M.
var C:MovieClip = new MovieClip;

// MovieClip C has a name "D" as of now.
C.name = "D";

// C named "D" becomes a child of M.
M.addChild(C);

trace(M.C); // undefined, because C is not a member of M object, it's just a local variable
trace(M.D); // undefined, because D is the name of MovieClip which is child of M MovieClip but not a member of M objest.
trace(M.getChildByName("C")); // null, because M has no children with name "C".
trace(M.getChildByName("D")); // [object MovieClip] because there is indeed a child with the name "D" inside of M.

// We create a field with the name "E" inside M object.
M.E = C;
trace(M.getChildByName("E")); // null, because M has no children with name "E".
trace(M.E); // [object MovieClip] because M now contains a field E with the reference to MovieClip C named "D".
```

Comment: @MichaelM Don't forget to mark the correct answer. :)

Comment: @MichaelM after some thought I added some explanations which might be helpful for you to understand how these things work.